# Node js native module, triggering callback from objective-c block event listener doesn't work

Tags: c++, node.js, cocoa, v8, objective-c++

I need to create a native node module that listens to an objective-c OSX event, and triggers a callback to javascript every time it happens:

```js
nativeAddon.listen(() => {
    console.log('It works!')
})
```

The callback works when immediately called in the `setUpCallback` function, but it doesn't fire from the objective-c observer block.

Here's what my main.mm file looks like

```cpp
using namespace v8;

Local<Function> event_callback;

void setUpCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    // Store the callback to be used in the runCallback function
    Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
    event_callback = cb;

    // THIS WORKS
    runCallback();

    // Listen to a mac event and trigger the callback when it happens
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserverForName:NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification object:NULL queue:NULL usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        // THIS DOESN'T WORK
        runCallback();
    }];
}

void runCallback() {
    auto isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();

    Local<Value> argv[1] = { String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "hello world", NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked() };

    auto fn = Local<Function>::New(isolate, event_callback);
    fn->Call(context, Null(isolate), 1, argv).ToLocalChecked();
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "listen", setUpCallback);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Initialize)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the type of `event_callback` from `Local<Function>` to `Persistent<Function>`.

The lifetime of a `Local` is tied to that of the `HandleScope` it was created in. Once the `HandleScope` goes out of scope (in your case, at the end of function `setUpCallback`), all Locals created while it was active become invalid. If you need a handle that *persists* after the `HandleScope` went away, you need to use a `Persistent`. More details here: https://v8.dev/docs/embed#advanced-guide.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `node-addon-api` and I tried `@jmrk`'s solution but it did not work for me. Changing the type to "Persistent" was not enough.

So I asked the question on GitHub [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/issues/800).

Because Mac events are triggered in a separate thread, you need to use a [`ThreadSafeFunction`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/threadsafe_function.md).

```c
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <napi.h>

Napi::ThreadSafeFunction tsfn;

// Trigger the JS callback when active space changes
void listenForActiveSpaceChange(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) {
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();

  // Create a ThreadSafeFunction
  tsfn = Napi::ThreadSafeFunction::New(
      env,
      info[0].As<Napi::Function>(), // JavaScript function called asynchronously
      "Active Space",               // Name
      0,                            // Unlimited queue
      1                             // Only one thread will use this initially
  );

  // Create a native callback function to be invoked by the TSFN
  auto callback = [](Napi::Env env, Napi::Function jsCallback) {
    // Call the JS callback
    jsCallback.Call({});
  };

  // Subscribe to macOS spaces change event
  [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
      addObserverForName:NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification
                  object:NULL
                   queue:NULL
              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                // Perform a blocking call
                napi_status status =
                    tsfn.BlockingCall(callback);
                if (status != napi_ok) {
                  NSLog(@"Something went wrong, BlockingCall failed");
                }
              }];
}

Napi::Object init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "listenForActiveSpaceChange"),
              Napi::Function::New(env, listenForActiveSpaceChange));

  return exports;
};

NODE_API_MODULE(mac_helper, init);
```